# Div background-image swap with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/32t3n1jo/

I am using jQuery to swap out a series of background images in a div. The swap is triggered by hovering over various text links.

I have used an existing jquery example I found to create the above jsfiddle which is working, but I need the background images to swap out on the div **'header-outer-blog'** *not* on the body tag.

I am new to js so I am finding it difficult to alter the code to suit.

How can I get the background image swap to occur on the div and not the body?

Thanks in advance.

```
jQuery(function(){
var $body = $('body');
$('.link-1').hover(function(){
    $body.css('background-image', 'url("http://placehold.it/10")')
}, function() {
    $body.css('background-image', '')
})
})

jQuery(function(){
var $body = $('body');
$('.link-2').hover(function(){
    $body.css('background-image', 'url("http://placehold.it/50")')
}, function() {
    $body.css('background-image', '')
})
})

jQuery(function(){
var $body = $('body');
$('.link-3').hover(function(){
    $body.css('background-image', 'url("http://placehold.it/100")')
}, function() {
    $body.css('background-image', '')
})
})

jQuery(function(){
var $body = $('body');
$('.link-4').hover(function(){
    $body.css('background-image', 'url("http://placehold.it/200")')
}, function() {
    $body.css('background-image', '')
})
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

https://jsfiddle.net/32t3n1jo/1/

You just had to **replace** `body` with your div's name:

```
jQuery(function(){
    var $body = $('.header-outer-blog');
    $('.link-1').hover(function(){
        $body.css('background-image', 'url("http://placehold.it/10")')
    }, function() {
        $body.css('background-image', '')
    })
})
```

Hope I helped.

---

**Updated** [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/32t3n1jo/5/) with a different way of organizing the functions:

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I needed, thank you. Is there a neater way of combining the separate functions in the js? Or do they need to be separated?

Comment: Please consider upvoting the answer. Regarding the functions, and even though it's not much of an improvement, you could go this way I think http://jsfiddle.net/32t3n1jo/5

Answer (score 0):

Your background-color is in the way of showing your images.

Try this:

```
jQuery(function(){
    initBackground('.link-1', '10');
    initBackground('.link-2', '50');
    initBackground('.link-3', '100');
    initBackground('.link-4', '200');
    initBackground('.link-5', '300');
    initBackground('.link-6', '200');
})

function initBackground(linkclass, image) {
    var $div = $('.header-outer-blog');
    $(linkclass).hover(function(){
        $div.css('background-image', 'url("http://placehold.it/' + image + '")');
        $div.css('background-color', 'transparent');
    }, function() {
        $div.css('background-image', '')
        $div.css('background-color', '#232328');
    });
}
```

Updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/32t3n1jo/4/

Comment: Thanks for the updated fiddle - but it looks like the background images are not working/loading.

Comment: I think the initial urls are missing an extension? perhaps .jpg? dunno :)

Comment: Found the problem.. was parsing the image var wrong: https://jsfiddle.net/32t3n1jo/4/